# Azure Stretching Database fails suddenly

Tags: sql-server, azure

Have previously and successfully utilized Azure Table stretching from SQL Server 2017. Today, I went to stretch a second database, and got an error.

Executed this script:

```
use [master]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DB To allow Stretch]
    SET REMOTE_DATA_ARCHIVE = ON  
        (  
            SERVER = 'workingstretchserver.database.windows.net' ,  
            CREDENTIAL = testedvalidcredential  
        ) ;  
GO
```

I am getting this weird message:

> Msg 45122, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   'Gen1 Data Warehouse has been deprecated in this region. Please leverage Gen2 Data Warehouse.'
>
> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

We do not use data warehousing. I also tried creating a new SQL Server database and server in Azure and still get the identical message. Has anyone run into this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with Azure.  Stretching is actually underpinned by Data Warehousing.

MS Support confirmed it.  MS Support was able to change settings on its end and restore functionality.  When the Gen2 upgrade is completed and MS solves the Stretching issue, the problem will go away; until then, contact support if you encounter this error.